# Combining SolrQueryByRange into solr.query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, console, solrnet

I am using solrnet to design my search engine. Now I have a requirement to query based on a date range. I have my query statement go like this.

```
  var matchingProducts = solr.Query(BuildQuery(parameters), new QueryOptions
  {
        FilterQueries = BuildFilterQueries(parameters),
        Rows = parameters.PageSize,
        Start = start,
        OrderBy = GetSelectedSort(parameters),
        SpellCheck = new SpellCheckingParameters { Collate = false },
        Highlight = new HighlightingParameters
        {
              Fields = new[] { strpara },
        },
        Facet = new FacetParameters
        {
              Queries = AllFacetFields.Except(SelectedFacetFields(parameters))
                       .Select(f => new SolrFacetFieldQuery(f) { MinCount = 1 })
                       .Cast<ISolrFacetQuery>().ToList(),
        },
  }
  );
```

Now how do I include my "SolrQueryByRange" command into this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Vignesh

Comment: I apologize if I was rude, I thought it would be obvious... quite obviously it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve, a SolrQueryByRange can go in the BuildQuery function or the BuildFilterQueries function

Comment: Thanks Mauricio. I checked out the solrnet query section and found that SolrQueryByRange comes under the FilterQueries section. Am incorporating this into my buildfilterqueries function.